# How to record screen in python for mac?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, numpy

I have currently written an python script that takes input from the user's video camera with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv
import datetime
import math
import time
import os
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def init():
    ret, imgBase = cap.read()
    print(type(imgBase))`
```

The above code is completely functional and it does get input from the user. However, instead of getting input from the user's web cam, I want to get input from user's screen. I need something like `cap = cv2.ScreenCapture(0)` I understand that that doesn't work, but I need something that does a similar function so I can read and capture an image from the user screen. In essence, I need to get a screenshot of the monitor/user's screen.

Answer (score 1):

Only works on Mac:

```
import os
os.system('screencapture out.jpg')
```

You can read the screenshot into memory using default python functions.
For further info type *man screencapture* in a terminal or check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work

    `import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import cv
    import datetime
    import math
    import time
    import os
    cap = os.system('screencapture out.jpg') #Changed this part
    def init():
        ret, imgBase = cap.read()
        print(type(imgBase))`

Comment: You will need to read the file from your filesystem after executing the command: `image = open('out.jpg', 'rb')`